# Drupal 7 Homebox module and Twitter Bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal Homebox module (https://drupal.org/project/homebox, version 7.x-2.0-beta6) to create a dashboard. I've found an issue that the save function to keep the status/location of blocks on the dashboard (closing or moving) doesn't work when using Twitter bootstrap theme. But there is no problem when using Batik theme. I could not find any clues of what cause this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i spent some hours but the solution is soo simple and unbelievable.
Search in the bootstrap theme under includes for the form.inc file. In this file all  fields are overwritten with . So the homebox is searching for an action and a input field but don`t find anyone. If you replace the else return value in this query:

```
  if (isset($element['#id']) && in_array($element['#id'], $whitelist)) {
    return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ">\n"; // This line break adds inherent margin between multiple buttons
  }
  else {
    return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>'. $label ."</button>\n"; // This line break adds inherent margin between multiple buttons
  }
```

with this:   `return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ">\n";` // This line break adds inherent margin between multiple buttons

you`ll get working the homebox.

Regards,
Alex from [Internetagentur München](http://www.crusoemedia.com)